# Setting img src from a list of provided images - Angular 4+

Tags: javascript, html, angular, image

I have a form where there are **3 empty `img` tags.** The user will be given a list of images (the images are held on the server). And user can select any image from the list set it as the `src` of one of the empty `img` tags.

**Current Code:**

```
<img style="width: 100px"  src="{{image1}}" onerror="this.src='http://localhost:3000/assets/images/ic_crop_original_black_48dp_2x.png';" href="#modal-sections" uk-toggle>
<img style="width: 100px"  src="{{image2}}" onerror="this.src='http://localhost:3000/assets/images/ic_crop_original_black_48dp_2x.png';" href="#modal-sections" uk-toggle>
<img style="width: 100px"  src="{{image3}}" onerror="this.src='http://localhost:3000/assets/images/ic_crop_original_black_48dp_2x.png';" href="#modal-sections" uk-toggle>
```

**The above outputs:**

[image]

These are the default images when no image is selected by the user.

**Please Note: When the user clicks on one of the default images it displays the image list in a popup.**

**Image list for the user to select an image from:**

[image]

The above is displayed within a popup.

**Setting an image:**

```
 <img src="/assets/images/cat1.svg" (click)="setImage('/assets/images/cat1.svg')">
```

Currently I set the image passing the `url` of the clicked on image to a `setImage()` method that assigns that `url` to the `src` of the image.

```
 image1: String;
 image2: String;
 image3: String;

setImage(url) {
   this.image1 = url;
}
```

**Issue:**

How can I make this more dynamic? So that a user can set `img src` for all 3 empty images individually. Current code seems very messy. I can't figure out a more better and dynamic way.

If the question does not make sense then please let me know and I'll explain again. Its a bit difficult to explain this one.

Answer (score 0):

I imagine something like this? Assuming the pop-up is part of the same class, you could store the URLs in an Array and *ngFor through them to create the elements. You can then change the URL of the index that was previously selected.

```
// Image elements
<img *ngFor="url of imgURLs; let i = index" (click)="setSelectedIndex(i)" [src]="url" style="width: 100px" onerror="this.src='http://localhost:3000/assets/images/ic_crop_original_black_48dp_2x.png';" href="#modal-sections" uk-toggle>

// Properties
imgURLs = ['', '', '']
selectedIndex: number;

// When selecting an empty image to set
setSelectedIndex(index: number) {
    this.selectedIndex = index;
}

// Setting the url of that selected index
setImage(url) {
   this.imgURLs[this.selectedIndex] = url;
}
```

Let me know if i have the wrong idea here.

Answer (score 0):

This will populate the default image list

```
<img *ngFor="let img of imageUrls; let i = index" (click)="setSelected(i)" [src]="img.image" style="width: 100px" onerror="this.src='http://localhost:3000/assets/images/ic_crop_original_black_48dp_2x.png';" href="#modal-sections" uk-toggle>
```

Add this code in the popup

```
<img *ngFor = "let image of imageList"  [src]="image.url" (click)="setImage(image)">
```

And your TS file should look like this

```
 currentSelected:number;
 imageUrls:any=[ { id:1, image:''},{ id:2, image:''},{ id:3, image:''}] //Selected image will save here 
 imageList:any =[
   { id :1,
     url:'https://placeimg.com/100/100/people'
   },
    {
      id :2,
     url:'https://placeimg.com/100/100/nature'
   },
    {
      id :3,
     url:'https://placeimg.com/100/100/tech'
   }
 ]
 setSelected(i){
   this.currentSelected = i;
 }
 setImage(image){
   this.imageUrls[this.currentSelected].image= image.url;
 }
```

**Note** I have placed some dummy images. let me know if it helps.